# Where to use "var' in javascript programs

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between using var and not using var in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)

Hello,

I am a self learned developer. Always, i write javascripts without the `var` for variables. But some javascripts use `var` for variables.

Both worked well for me. I am bit confused by this.

Is Writing scripts with `var` a standard form or they used only within classes ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between using var and not using var in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript), [Javascript: is using ‘var’ to declare variables optional?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485423/javascript-is-using-var-to-declare-variables-optional), [JavaScript variable scope question: to var, or not to var](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956296/javascript-variable-scope-question-to-var-or-not-to-var), found via SO search for `javascript var` ;)

Comment: Thanks felix Kling ! moderators can close this post if needed !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`var` limits the scope of a variable to the function it is declared in, if you don't use `var` you create a global.

Globals tend to lead to code that is hard to maintain and suffers from race conditions.

Always use `var` unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that race conditions are the problem, since Javascript (Web Workers aside) execution is single-threaded. IMO, a better statement of the problem is namespace pollution and state stomping (accidentally overwriting data you need).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `var`, the variable will be global, not limited in the scope you're in (a problem for say another variable in the global space with the same name, you just over-wrote it, probably unintentionally).

Short version: always use `var` to be safe.